# How to access the object that used Decorator?

Tags: javascript, decorator

I want to inject some HTML Elements that requires from many components by using decorator. This is the usage I want to implement:

```
const serializedCSS = '...';    // Serialized CSS

@injectStyle(serializedCSS);
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
   ...
```

I want to send serialized css to decorator, however I can't found how to access the "MyComponent" class, I have to access it's own property to create new style element and append as child.

```
function injectStyle(target: any) {
    console.log(target);

    // ??? HOW TO ACCESS THE OBJECT? ///

    function f(...args:any) {

    }

    return f;
}
```

I can't find any related solution about this. Any advice will very appreciate it!

Comment: You mean you want to access the object created when calling `new MyComponent` ?

Comment: @mins I want to access object that after used with new keyword, to access internal properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the my solution.

```
export function injectStyle(css:string, ...args:any) {
    return function(target:any) {
        // Now I can access target object with "target"!
        target.doSomething ... 
        ...
    };
}
```

Now I can use injectStyle decorator something like this:

```
@injectStyle(require('./style.css'))
class App extends HTMLElement {
    ...
}
```